# In "The King's English" the Fowlers consider the term "record price" to be slang - are there available alternatives?

Tags: phrase-requests

On page 61 of "The King's English", third edition, H W Fowler and F G Fowler, the following sentence is given, with the word "record" being marked as slang: "A Sevres vase sold yesterday at Christie’s realized what is believed to be the record price of 4,000 guineas"

Looking on the Oxford English Dictionary website, the first reference they give for "record-breaking" is 1882, and the first edition of "The King's English" was published in 1906, so I understand that the term was new when they wrote their book, but I have no idea what alternative sentences they might have had in mind; I can't think of any good substitute for the term "record price"

It's not that I am concerned about using a term that was considered to be informal then, it's that I'm wondering how could that sentence be recast in a non-awkward way to avoid that term

Comment: "highest ever price".

Comment: I don't think there's a single word that could replace "record" here - Fowler would probably have suggested something like "A Sèvres vase was sold yesterday at Christie's for 4,000 guineas, which is believed to be the highest price ever realized by such a vase", but I don't think we can say definitely what the "correct" wording would be.

Comment: FWIW, **realized** is rarely used in that sense any more.

Comment: @TimR - they also marked "realized" as slang, but I wasn't interested in that aspect and so I didn't mention it

Comment: If "record price of 4,000 guineas" is unacceptable what about just "a record 4,000 guineas" or "a record-breaking 4,000 guineas"? Are you opposed to all uses of "record" or just the specific "record price"?

Comment: @Stuart F - I am not opposed to any of these uses of "record", the Fowlers were opposed to all these uses, and I was asking about what alternate expressions could be used, as "record" seems such a good option to me

Comment: It would be useful to see what Fowler's definition of "slang" is. I suspect that, today, we would use "informal" in many cases.

Comment: "Realized" is very common in the auction field currently.

Comment: @TimR, also "realized profits" and "realized capital gains" are very common expressions in finance. If those aren't the same usage as in OP's example, they're very closely related.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, they're related.  But the verb **realized** used in that commercial sense has been duking it out with **realize** in the "suddenly dawned on me" sense since the turn of the 20th century and is on its way downhill.  Compare these two ngrams:  (1) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+sale+realized%2CI+suddenly+realized&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3  and (2)https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+sale+realized&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: 'Unprecedented' might be considered to work. 'Highest to date' is the default reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Guernica* was sold yesterday for what is believed to be **the highest price ever recorded** for a Picasso painting in the postapocalyptic era, a dozen cans of baked beans.

Comment: I had considered something a bit like this, but it seemed long and awkward - perhaps it is not as awkward as I thought

Comment: What makes it a tad awkward is "what is believed to be". But "the highest price ever recorded"  itself is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wordnik, among other noun definitions at [record](https://www.wordnik.com/words/record), gives "an unsurpassed measurement". Perhaps **unsurpassed** would work.

Comment: Though it wouldn't work with somethat that happened as recently as "yesterday":  *The painting sold yesterday for an unsurpassed price of $20 million.